# Ember Serialize in link-to doesn't work since 1.4.0?

Tags: ember.js

Since I've upgraded from 1.3.2 to 1.4.0 I've got many problems about the serialization of the link-to url.

In the previous version, for each link-to we pass in the serialize method but it's not the case anymore, Can someone tell me why and if there is another alternative?

Thank u

Comment: Could you provide some code ? https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.4.0/CHANGELOG.md

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution !

Actually my route looks like this :

```
this.route('projects', {
        path: '/projects/:pageProjects/:colProjects/:ascProjects'
});
```

And my handlebar looks like this :

```
{{#link-to "projects"}}
     {{trc "plural" "Signed"}} <span class="pull-right">{{count.approuvedCount}}</span>
 {{/link-to}}
```

The fact is that sometime I needed to set a default model directly in the serialize method which is not a great solution and I know it.

Since the ember ugrade to 1.4.0, if we don't pass any model parameter into the link-to, it doesn't call the serialize method anymore :).